# Taylor polynomial converging pointwise but not uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Many standard examples of Taylor series $(\exp(x), \sin(x), \cos(x))$ converge uniformly, others don't converge to its original function at all, e.g. $\exp(-x^{-2})$. I couldn't think of any smooth function $f$ with its Taylor polynomial converging to $f$ pointwise but not uniformly. What would be a simple example?

Comment: Try the Taylor series for $f(x)  = {1 \over 1-x}$ on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: There are no examples. In any compact subset of the interval/disc of convergence, the convergence is uniform.

Comment: (On the other hand, the convergence tends not to be uniform on the entire interval/disc of convergence, but this is a bit misleading as one never seems to actually need that much.)

Comment: Also, $f(x) = e^x$ doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. As Andres points out, on compact sets the convergence (within the ROC) is uniform, so any example must be on a non-compact set.